# Cocoa controller question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I have a two windows app. First one is the default window. Second one is created using a custom controller:

```
CCCVentanaBloqueo *ctrl = [[CCCVentanaBloqueo alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"VentanaBloqueo"];
CCWVentanaBloqueo *ventana = (CCWVentanaBloqueo*)[ctrl window];
```

**ventana** contains one label connected to one **CCCVentanaBloqueo** controller outlet via XCode IB. If I try two modify that outlet from main window via **CCCVentanaBloqueo** controller outlet, no change succed.

I can see that outlet has a nil value. I can see also that two **CCCVentanaBloqueo** objects are created (two calls to awakeFromNib function) when [ctrl window] line gets executed.

I suppose *ctrl references wrong controller but I don't know why two controllers are created.

Do you know why? Any other way to make changes to not main window from main window controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the second window controller as an instance variable of your app controller and make it a property. Then you can easily send messages to it's IBOutlets (provided they are also properties) via the appDelegate.

Let's say you're going to have window A send window B a message. In Window A's controller you might have a method like this:

```
- (IBAction)messageWindowB:(id)sender {

       myAppDelegate *appDelegate = [NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
       [appDelegate.windowB.theView doSomething];

}
```

Honestly, I am not sure if I entirely understood your question. Also, this is a quick and dirty approach. So if anyone else has suggestions, please be my guest!

Comment: Which is the difference between using the app delegate and the file's owner?

Comment: File's owner is a proxy object, typically standing for the controller that you choose to load the NIB with. The main window's file's owner is NSApplication, which doesn't exactly concern the delegation of messages within your app in a practical sense (although it does own the appDelegate, which does). The appDelegate, on the other hand, sits at the very top of your app in terms of delegating messages to the various components of your app.

Comment: In the standard cocoa app template, the main window has an appDelegate object, which is to suggest that since the main window will be interacting with almost all components of your app, it may require access to the topmost level of message delegation. So in this case, you would be declaring your second window's controller as in instance variable and property of the appDelegate so you could consistently send it messages when needed.

Comment: However, there are lots of ways in general to accomplish what you are needing. For example, you could use a more notification-based design pattern in which you have one window simply post a notification that the other window is registered to listen for. But that's a different story!